# Adding triangle to a consisting octagon in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick]
        % GrÃ¶sse (Umkreisradius) des Achtecks
        \pgfmathparse{3.5}\let\r\pgfmathresult
        % Punkte erstellen
        \foreach \a/\l in {0/A,1/B,2/C,3/D,4/E,5/F,6/G,7/H}
        {
            \pgfmathparse{\a*45+247.5}\let\b\pgfmathresult
            \coordinate (\l) at (\b:\r);
            \draw (\b:1.1*\r) node {$\l$};
        }
        \draw(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--cycle;

        \foreach \l in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}
        {
            \filldraw[fill=white,draw=black] (\l) circle (1pt);
        }

        % Winkel von S = Winkel von B
        \pgfmathparse{45+247.5}\let\ab\pgfmathresult
        % Winkel von C
        \pgfmathparse{45+\ab}\let\ac\pgfmathresult
        % Y-Koordinate von S = r*sin(C)
        \pgfmathparse{\r*sin(\ac)}\let\sy\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathparse{-\sy*tan(\ab-270)}\let\sx\pgfmathresult


        \coordinate(S) at (\sx,\sy);

        \draw[orange,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt] (A) -- (D);
        \draw[orange,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt] (B) -- (F);

        \filldraw[fill=white,draw=orange] (S) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west]{$S$};

        \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt,->] (A) -- (H);
        \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt,->] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Now I would like to alter the code in a way such that I get

[image]

where the angles of the added triangle are 45 degrees on the hypothenuse and in the tip 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit cryptic but I guess it will do

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\zzz{2cm}
\draw (0,0) foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {A,...,H}{
  node[label={[anchor=\xi*45+60,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=4pt]:\x},
       draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=1pt] (\x){}
  --++(\xi*45:\zzz) 
};
\draw[orange] (A) -- (D) (B) -- (F);
\draw (B) -- ($(A)!2!($(A)!(D)!(B)$)$) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TheGeekGreek my pleasure

Answer (score 2):

You can use tikz to calculate intersections:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every node/.style = {draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, fill=white}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, >=stealth]
\def\zzz{3.5cm}
\draw (0,0) foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {A,...,H}{
  node[label={[anchor=\xi*45+60,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=4pt]:\x}] (\x){}
  --++(\xi*45:\zzz)
};
\draw[orange] (A) -- (D) (B) -- (F);
\draw[red, ->] (A) edge (H) (A) edge (B);
\draw (B) -- (intersection of E--D and A--B) -- (D);
\node[draw=orange, label=right:S] at (intersection of A--D and B--F) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Thanks to percusse's answer for the octagon code.)